# Transformation of metric by diffeomorphism: pushforward or pullback?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, conventions, definition, diffeomorphism-invariance

Let $(M,g)$ be a smooth manifold with a metric tensor of signature $(p,q)$. The signature isn't really important for this question so we leave it general.

If $\Phi : M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism we can define both the pushforward $\Phi_\ast$ and the pullback $\Phi^\ast$ acting on tensors of arbitrary type $(r,s)$.

Furthermore, the two are connected by the formula

$$\Phi^\ast= (\Phi^{-1})_\ast\tag{1}$$

In particular, we are able to define both the pushforward and the pullback of the metric.

Now, in Wald's GR textbook, it seems he transforms the metric by the pushforward, so that $g\mapsto \Phi_\ast g$ (just one small caveat: Wald uses the opposite to what seems the standard notation and calls $\Phi^\ast$ the pushforward and $\Phi_\ast$ the pullback).

On the other hand, in Carroll's GR textbook, it seems he transforms the metric by the pullback, so that $g\mapsto \Phi^\ast g$.

My question is: what is the difference between these two approaches? I mean, because of (1) their definitions are interchanged if we trade $\Phi\leftrightarrow\Phi^{-1}$. But is there one difference in interpretation?

What is going on in here? Why would one define it in one way instead of the other? The pullback seems more natural, since it doesn't need to involve $\Phi^{-1}$, but still I think there may be a difference in interpretation depending on what is the convention we set for this.

Comment: $\Phi^*g$ makes sense even if $\Phi$ is not a diffeomorphism, so it is more general. I don't think I have ever seen people try to develop stuff with isometries and what have you focusing mainly on push-forwards.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a misapplication of the concept of pushforward and pullback. Carroll is speaking the language of physicists, but I think in the language of a modern differential geometer, tensors such as the metric do *not* transform under a change of coordinates. The tensor is invariant, but its components can be expressed in different bases.

Assuming I'm getting the idea of pushforward and pullback right, these are maps from one tangent space into some other tangent space, which may be on a completely different manifold, not even necessarily of the same dimension. When we talk about transforming the metric, we're talking about a change of basis that occurs at *one* point in the spacetime, which is fixed. There are two different bases, but they're bases for the same tangent space.

Comment: The metric is indeed changed, in this question.